# How do you calculate rowMeans by column name, not column number

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following df `bhs1`:

```
structure(list(bhs1_1 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), bhs1_2 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_3 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), bhs1_4 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_5 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), bhs1_6 = c(NA, 
1, NA, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 2, 1, 
2, NA, 1, 1, 2), bhs1_7 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_8 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_9 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), bhs1_10 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2), bhs1_11 = c(NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1), bhs1_12 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_13 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), bhs1_14 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1), bhs1_15 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), bhs1_16 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_17 = c(NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), bhs1_18 = c(NA, 
1, NA, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1), bhs1_19 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), bhs1_20 = c(NA, 
2, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`bhs1` was passed through `as_tibble()`.

I am interested in calculating a new variable `bhs1$total`, that is the prorated mean across variables `bhs1_1:bhs1_20`. The reason for prorating means is so that observations with missing values can be compared to observations without missing values. At the risk of stating the obvious:

- observation 1 may only have data on 18 variables, so I need to sum the recorded variables, ignore the `NAs` and, then divide by 18 to have a mean comparable to,
- observation 2 who has data on 20 variables, who would have the summed recorded variables divided by 20.

I am aware of (although do not yet know how to execute) multiple imputation, but I do not want to use this for this exercise.

I have tried the following code:

```
# A tibble: 908 x 21
   bhs1_1 bhs1_2 bhs1_3 bhs1_4 bhs1_5 bhs1_6 bhs1_7 bhs1_8 bhs1_9
 *  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 2      1      2      1      2      1      1      1      2      1
 3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 4      2      2      2      1      1      2      1      2      2
 5      1      1      2      1      2      1      2      2      1
 6      2      1      2      1      2      2      1      2      1
 7      2      2      2      1      2      2      1      2      1
 8      2      1      2      1      2      2      1      2      1
 9      1      2      2      1      2      2      1      1      2
10      2      2      2      1      2      1      1      2      1
# ... with 898 more rows, and 12 more variables: bhs1_10 <dbl>,
#   bhs1_11 <dbl>, bhs1_12 <dbl>, bhs1_13 <dbl>, bhs1_14 <dbl>,
#   bhs1_15 <dbl>, bhs1_16 <dbl>, bhs1_17 <dbl>, bhs1_18 <dbl>,
#   bhs1_19 <dbl>, bhs1_20 <dbl>, meanTest <dbl>
```

Which works as expected. However, when I enter the column names instead of the column numbers, it fails:

```
> bhs1$meanTest <- rowMeans(bhs1[,"bhs1_1":"bhs1_20"], na.rm=TRUE)

Error in "bhs1_1":"bhs1_20" : NA/NaN argument
   5. check_names_df(j, x)
   4. `[.tbl_df`(bhs1, , "bhs1_1":"bhs1_20")
   3. bhs1[, "bhs1_1":"bhs1_20"]
   2. is.data.frame(x)
   1. rowMeans(bhs1[, "bhs1_1":"bhs1_20"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

I think it is much more straight forward to use variable / column names instead of column numbers. Is there an elegant way to write code to meet this use case? If so, can someone please point me in the right direction and/or provide me with a sample?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to get a vector of names

```
nm1 <- paste0("bhs1_", 1:20)
bhs1$meanTest <- rowMeans(bhs1[nm1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

If the names are not having a pattern and we are interested to subset between the start and stop names, then use `match` to get the column index, get a sequence (`:`)

```
nm1 <- Reduce(`:`, match(c("bhs1_1", "bhs1_20"), names(bhs1)))
```

and use that in `rowMeans`

---

Or if we are using the `tidyverse`, we can specify the range (`:`)

```
bhs1 <- bhs1 %>%
          select(bhs1_1:bhs1_20) %>% #can replace with 'nm1'
          rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE) %>%
          bind_cols(bhs1, meanTest = .)
```

---

If we need to do the `rowMeans` on multiple sets of columns, use the `map2` from `purrr` by either passing it as a list of quosures for the 'start' and 'end' column names in `map2` and then do the `select`  by evaluating (`!!`) the quosures to get the `rowMeans` afterwards

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(quos(bhs1_1, bhs1_4), quos(bhs1_5, bhs1_8), ~
         bhs1 %>%
           select((!! .x) : (!! .y)) %>% 
           rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   bind_cols(bhs1, .)
```

---

Or we can pass as a vector of strings and then do the conversion to symbol (with `sym` from `rlang`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
map2(c("bhs1_1", "bhs1_4"), c("bhs1_5", "bhs1_8"), ~ 
           bhs1 %>%
              select(!!(rlang::sym(.x)): !!(rlang::sym(.y)))) %>%
              rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    bind_cols(bhs1, .)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I can get the first example to work, but not the second one i.e., it does not add a column `meanTest` as the first one does. Is it supposed to?

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski  We need to do the assignment `bhs1 <-`

Comment: Of course, that works. Thanks. I think once I get my head around the `tidyverse` way of doing things, it will work much better. The `select()` function seems very intuitive and powerful. I just have to get used to all the extra lines. Can you please explain what the `.` in `rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE)` means. And also what ` bind_cols(bhs1, meanTest = .)` does?

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski The `.` represents the data that is being passed out from the earlier step i.e. `select`.  So, here we are taking the rowMeans of the subset of columns, which is a vector of values..  With `bind_cols`, we bind the original dataset with the vector (`.`) from the rowMeans step.  To better understand this, run each step and check the output i.e. `bhs %>% select(bhs1_1:bhs1_20)` and then add the `rowMeans`

Comment: —THANKS! That was very informative. If I wanted to run other variables through a similar process as you described, would I just repeat the steps again, or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski  Are you saying that there are separate groups of columns that you want to get the `mean` of

Comment: that is correct. So for example, in my data set there are other columns e.g., `inq1_1:1nq1_7` and `inq1_8:inq1_15` that I would like seperate means for e.g., `pb1` and `tb1` respectively.

Comment: @AtanasJanackovski  In that case use a `Map` or `map2` (from `purrr`) `map2(c('inq1_1', 'inq1_8'), c('inq1_7, 'inq1_15), ~ bhs1 %>% select(.x: .y) %>% rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170147/discussion-between-atanas-janackovski-and-akrun).